# How to Hide subfolder in subversion for team members

Tags: svn, version-control

Using apache subversion 1.10.

I had a parent folder named 'test', and two subfolder 'test/folderA', 'test/folderB'.

I want : Everyone can access '**test**', but some members can only see '**test/folderA**', while others can only see '**test/folderB**'.

svn auth config is:

```
[/test]
* = rw
[/test/folderA]
userA = 
[/test/folderB]
userB =
```

But... when userA checkout **test**, an error occured but **test/folderA** can be download successfully.

so, any ideas to control **folderA** invisible for userA and visible for userB?

Comment: You need to show configuration file (e.g. httpd.conf) of your server and events from the server's log

Comment: The main problem is not the error, but how to control unauthorized folder invisible.

Comment: you may want to reword your question because I am not sure whether I understand it. However, consider wildcard permissions - https://subversion.apache.org/docs/release-notes/1.10.html#authzperf

Answer (score 0):

Here is my final solution, for anyone with the same problem.

I tried apache svn 1.10 and 1.7, all failed. If you have the permission of a folder, then you have the access to EVERYTHING in this folder, even if you manually set subfolder with `* =`

My final solution is using [Subversion Edge](https://www.collab.net/downloads/subversion),  then I can set rw to the parent folder, then set *= to some subfolder, which is perfect for my situation.